# Unable to run the javascript that using CryptoJS library in JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, cryptojs, scriptengine

I'm trying to run the JS function in Java code and the JS function is not executing since it had some third party library that needs to be load.

**JsFunction.js**

```
load('crypto-js-3.1.9/crypto-js.js');

var encrypterId = function(name) {

    var context_data = {"referralId": name};

    var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(context_data))

    var encoded_referral_id = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(secret);

    return encoded_referral_id;
}
```

**JavaCode:**

```
public static void runDisplay() {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        try {
            engine.eval(new FileReader("./resources/JsFunction.js"));
            Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
            Object result;
            result = invocable.invokeFunction("encrypterId", "827AE1001sdsj213jasu721kkao@1sa");
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot load script from crypto-js-3.1.9/crypto-js.js in <eval> at line number 1
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:469)
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:453)
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:405)
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:401)
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:149)
```

Can someone help me to run this JS and return the value ? else is it possible to write the equivalent code in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it this way:

Remove the 'load' line from JsFunction.js

In your JavaCode, in the line immediately before `engine.eval(new FileReader("./resources/JsFunction.js"));` just insert a line `engine.eval(new FileReader("./resources/crypto-js-3.1.9/crypto-js.js"));`

I believe that puts the contents of the crypto-js.js file into scope in the ScriptEngine, and the subsequent JsFunction.js call should work.

I did something similar with much simpler JS files as a test case.